# How to write to a file the messages a ROS node is subscribed to?

Tags: python, ros

I know about ROS publishing and subscribing nodes. This question is specifically about nodes that are subscribed to a message.
Now according to the [documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29) a simple subscriber would be like

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String

def callback(data):
    rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id() + "I heard %s", data.data)
    #write to the text file here
    
def listener():
    rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber("chatter", String, callback)

    #Open a text file here?

    # spin() simply keeps python from exiting until this node is stopped
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener()
```

Here the `callback` simply logs the message (`data`).
However, what would happen if I want to save this message to a file?

The standard way to do this would be to open a text file after defining the node subscription (in the place there is a comment) with something like `f = open('path/to/csv_file', 'w')` and then writing on the text file in the callback function (also a comment in the code above)

However if I do this, the opened file is not assured to be closed anywhere, right? Is there a chance that if I Ctrl-C this node when running, there could be some data that is not written to the file since it is not closed properly?

In few words: what is the correct way to code a ROS node that is subscribed to a message and write this message on a file?

(Note: I don't think -or have not figure it out- if I can use `with` to handle files here)

Answer (score 3):

ROS is callbacks are called as long as the blocking call `rospy.spin()` runs. This function is left if the process is cancelled. This means you can do use the `with` statement to ensure your file is closed properly afterwards:

```
with open('path/to/csv_file', 'w') as f:
   rospy.spin()
```

and in your callback you can then write the message to the file:

```
def callback(data):
    f.write(data.data)
```